# Why is my thread execution jumping between CPU cores?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I recently started experimenting with std::thread and I tried running a small program that displays the webcam feed in a separate thread and I am using OpenCV. I am just doing this for "educational" purposes. What I noticed was that the thread seemed to keep jumping between cores which striked me as odd since I thought that the overhead of this change would not be worth it from an efficiency/performance side of view. Does anybody know the root/reason for such behavior?
Short disclaimer --> I am new to StackOverflow so if I missed something, please let me know.

[A snapshot of my system monitor - Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXPr8.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp> //openCV functionality
#include <time.h> //timing functionality
#include <thread>



using namespace cv;

using namespace std;

void webcam_func(){
    Mat image;



namedWindow("Display window");

VideoCapture cap(0);

if (!cap.set(CAP_PROP_AUTO_EXPOSURE , 10)){
    std::cout <<"Exposure could not be set!" <<std::endl;
    //return -1 ;
}


if (!cap.isOpened()) {

cout << "cannot open camera";

    }
int i = 0;
while (i < 1000000) {

cap >> image;

Size s = image.size();
int rows = s.height;
int cols = s.width;

imshow("Display window", image);
double fps = cap.get(CAP_PROP_FPS);
//cout << "Frames per second using video.get(CAP_PROP_FPS) : " << fps << endl;

//cout <<"The height of the video is " <<rows <<endl;
//cout <<"The width of the video is " <<cols <<endl;
std::thread::id this_id = std::this_thread::get_id();   
std::cout << "thread id -->  " << this_id <<std::endl;
waitKey(25);

i++ ;
std::cout <<"Counter value " <<i <<std::endl; 

    }


}

int main() {

std::thread t1(webcam_func);    

while(true){

}


return 0;

}
```

Comment: UI operations like `cv::imshow`, `cv::waitKey` are usually done only on the main thread (also called the UI thread). I haven't tried calling them from another thread, but I imagine they will invoke the main thread all the same.

Comment: I would suggest offloading calculations to separate threads as needed, but keeping the UI inteactions on the main thread.

Comment: In general threads are not tied to a particular processor core and it’s the OS scheduler job to efficiently distribute threads among all available cores. Here, the OS may switch your thread to another core to better manage heating. However, there are usually options to pin a thread to a particular CPU core if needed.

Comment: [This](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/c11-threads-affinity-and-hyperthreading/) article explains the behavior you observed and the means to pin a thread to particular logical core in detail.

Comment: @wohlstad I was not aware of the UI operations necessarily calling the main thread. Seems weird though because in the case you would want multiple cv::imshow from different threads your main thread will be overworked?

Comment: @LouisLac The heating part makes sense to me but the time a core keeps executing the thread is really low so I would at least imagine this change to happen after some time. I will look further into the article you provided. Thank you.

Comment: Note that I personally observed the exact same behavior as you while executing a CPU-intensive program with only one thread) on an Ubuntu machine, so I believe that is it pretty common and probably well documented.

Comment: @user18292845 to be honest I do not know how `cv::imshow` is implemented. At least on Windows the common design is to defer all such operations to the UI (i.e. main) thread. Not sure at all about Linux, but I wouldn't be surprised if the principle is the same.

Comment: As a data point: On my Windows PC there are right now 1450 threads sharing 8 cores. Pinning each thread to its own core might not be the best way to assure throughput, or response time. The scheduler might not realize that you are watching a video stream.  :-)

Comment: I want to point out that I am trying to logically think about it while practically also trying to  learn more about it. I was thinking that in an embedded setting for example (provided that we are working on system that can host an OS) you would want to have full control over what and how it is happening in your software. @BoP pinning might not be the way to go as you suggest but that might create more confusion when debugging or generally when trying to pinpoint the reasons behind unwanted behavior.

Comment: @wohlstad imshow/waitkey _do not "invoke"_ the main thread. please don't speculate. the source for that is all open. events are processed *in waitKey*. some gui libraries don't like that to be done other than in the main thread. -- that's not the issue here. the question is why do threads jump cores, and the answer is: "because the OS scheduler feels like it"

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz - at least on Windows - don't they use the Win32 windowing API ? I'm quite sure in this case rendering etc. is done on the main thread. Am I wrong ?

Comment: your concept of the process is flawed, as evidenced by the choice of words. I can't explain that in a chat environment. the issue is your concept of who/what has agency and what "is done" and who is doing it and what happens if that is done differently.

Comment: I can't combat all the misconceptions because I have no idea which there are. all I can do is try to explain carefully and hope you can tell how you need to adjust your ideas. -- GUIs always work with an "event loop". the OS sends events to the process. the event loop is supposed to run in the main thread. it receives the events and deals with them, e.g. by redrawing some elements, or calling event handlers (click event etc). -- anything causing changes to the gui from a different thread can cause trouble because those functions **aren't necessarily thread-safe**.

Comment: threads are not "invoked". threads run (are started). threads can end. *functions* can be "invoked". -- windows don't "belong to threads". windows are objects of a GUI toolkit. they are, like every other piece of data, accessible by all threads in a process. again, whether that's threadsafe or not depends on the GUI toolkit. -- many GUI toolkits will flip their shit if you call any GUI functions (any manipulation of the GUI at all) from any thread other than the one that runs the event loop. -- the event loop does not "move". it is always executed by the same thread (should be main thread)

Comment: this question is on operating system concepts _or_ OS-specific implementation, not programming. I'd send this off to cs.stackexchange.com or https://superuser.com/ or https://serverfault.com/ or perhaps something OS-specific like https://unix.stackexchange.com/ -- in any case, the effect of threads jumping between cores does not require OpenCV for demonstration.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thanks for the explanation. I agree my wording was quite poor. I am ware of the message/event loop you mentioned. I meant that this loop (as well as all the functions that are called by it) are executed on the main thread. I imagine calling `cv::imshow` from any thread eventually causes the rendring functions to be called by the message loop (and therefore on the main thread). that is what I meant by "invoke" but as I said I agree it is inaccurate.

Comment: in the case of OpenCV, the message loop is spun by waitKey/pollKey (which calls whatever GUI library's event loop processing), and that ought to be called in the main thread only. if it's called anywhere else, including in event handlers, it will cause trouble. some GUI toolkits outright throw it all in your face. others seem to tolerate it, perhaps with subtle heisenbugs. -- stuff like imshow _might_ post some messages to the message queue (which the event loop consumes), but it also might directly call GUI code... and then you still need to know if that's safe to call from multiple threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default Linux scheduler schedule tasks (eg. threads) for a given quantum (time slice) on available processing units (eg. cores or hardware threads). This quantum can be interrupted if a task enters in *sleeping mode* or **wait for something** (inputs, locks, etc.). `waitKey(25)` exactly does that: it causes your thread to wait for a short period of time. The thread execution is interrupted and a **context-switch** is done. The OS can execute other tasks during this time. When the computing thread is ready again (because >25 ms has elapsed), the scheduler can schedule it again. It tries to execute the task on the same processing unit so to reduce overheads (eg. cache misses) but the previous processing unit can be still used by another thread when the computing task is being scheduled back. This is unlikely to be the case when there is not many ready tasks or just greedy ones though. Additionally, some processors supports SMT (aka. hyper-threading). For example, many x86-64 Intel processors supports 2 hardware threads per core sharing the same caches. Context-switches between 2 hardware threads lying on the same core are significantly cheaper (eg. far less cache-misses). Also note that the Linux scheduler is not perfect like most other schedulers. In fact, it was bogus few years ago and not even able to fill all available cores when it was possible (see: [The Linux Scheduler: a Decade of Wasted Cores](https://people.ece.ubc.ca/sasha/papers/eurosys16-final29.pdf)). Finally, note that the (direct) overhead of a context-switch is no more than few dozens of micro-seconds on a mainstream Linux PC so having them every few dozens of milliseconds is fine (<1% overhead).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. This makes more sense now and I can understand that from an efficiency point of view it is not that bad. Furthermore in the case of being able to follow execution more carefully you could pin the thread to a specific core if needed.